# OpenMP, how do I treat these variables?

Tags: c, multithreading, debugging, openmp, variable-declaration

I've been trying to teach myself OpenMP, in fact I started today by looking at some examples. I tried to expand on one of those examples by making a program that can pick out the highest number, the lowest number, their coordinates and the total value of all elements from a 2d array.

Here's an excerpt from the code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:total) reduction(max : max) reduction (min : min) private(j)
for( i=0;i<size; i++){
    for(j=0; j<size;j++){
        total += arr[i][j];
        if(arr[i][j] > max){
            #pragma omp critical
            {
                if(arr[i][j] > max){
                   max=arr[i][j];
                   maxX=i;
                   maxY=j;
                }
            }
        }
         if(arr[i][j] < min){
            #pragma omp critical
            {
                if(arr[i][j] < min){
                   min=arr[i][j];
                   minX=i;
                   minY=j;
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

The only thing that seems to be wrong are the coordinates `maxX`, `maxY`, `minX` and `minY`. From execution to execution (*with more than 1 thread*) their values change, sometimes giving the right answer, but mostly not.

What do I need to do to these variables to get this right?

Comment: Do you use total? It looks like a reduction(+:).  maxX, maxY, minX, minY appear to require firstprivate lastprivate clauses.

Comment: @tim18 Yeah, after looking those up it seems like they would work.
Lastprivate to get the last value of the variables in the iterations and firstprivate to make sure the variables are initialized correctly, right?

But I'm a complete beginner, where would I place those clauses?

Comment: Private list clauses are appended to your omp parallel

Comment: @tim18 I figured. It still isn't working right, though it's now deterministic so there's that.
Shouldn't the variables be shared so later when all threads have completed the main thread can just read the last thing written into `maxX` and `maxY`?

Comment: Maybe irrelevant, but it seems like a bad idea to use `max` as a variable name and a function name.

Comment: @Jonathan Chiang I guess it looks kind of odd but it's not really going to cause any confusion over which is which. I wound up "solving" my issue by removing the min/max reduction clauses anyway.